# Speaker similarity using Resemblyzer

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech

I am using Resemblyzer to get the similarity chart for the speakers in an MP3 file that I have. But I am getting an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'ExtAudioFile' object has no attribute 'closed'
```

The code:

```
from resemblyzer import preprocess_wav, VoiceEncoder
from demo_utils import *
from pathlib import Path

wav_fpath = Path("/Users/...")
wav = preprocess_wav(wav_fpath)
```

Entire error log:

```
/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/util/decorators.py:88: UserWarning: PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead.
  return f(*args, **kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 164, in load
    y, sr_native = __soundfile_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 195, in __soundfile_load
    context = sf.SoundFile(path)
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 629, in __init__
    self._file = self._open(file, mode_int, closefd)
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1183, in _open
    _error_check(_snd.sf_error(file_ptr),
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1357, in _error_check
    raise RuntimeError(prefix + _ffi.string(err_str).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
RuntimeError: Error opening '/Users/sankalpbhatia/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop/voice_similarity/meta_full_qa.mp3': File contains data in an unknown format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop/voice_similarity/test_two.py", line 14, in <module>
    wav = preprocess_wav(wav_fpath)
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/resemblyzer/audio.py", line 27, in preprocess_wav
    wav, source_sr = librosa.load(fpath_or_wav, sr=None)
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/util/decorators.py", line 88, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 170, in load
    y, sr_native = __audioread_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 226, in __audioread_load
    reader = audioread.audio_open(path)
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/audioread/__init__.py", line 111, in audio_open
    return BackendClass(path)
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/audioread/macca.py", line 200, in __init__
    url = CFURL(filename)
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/audioread/macca.py", line 140, in __init__
    filename = filename.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'encode'
Exception ignored in: <function CFObject.__del__ at 0x7feee048e3a0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/audioread/macca.py", line 134, in __del__
    _corefoundation.CFRelease(self._obj)
AttributeError: 'CFURL' object has no attribute '_obj'
Exception ignored in: <function ExtAudioFile.__del__ at 0x7feee048eb80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/audioread/macca.py", line 335, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/Users/sankalpbhatia/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/audioread/macca.py", line 329, in close
    if not self.closed:
AttributeError: 'ExtAudioFile' object has no attribute 'closed'
(base) Sankalps-MacBook-Air:voice_similarity sankalpbhatia$
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does the error log have any extra information, e.g. in which file the error happens, at what line? If you can, please post the entire error log. In this case the error doesn't happen within your script itself, but one of the modules called, much easier to figure out where if you give us the logs.

Comment: I have now added the error log @OttoHanski

Comment: According to the first error, it would appear that the python library fails at reading the mp3 file due to the file containing the audio data in some unrecognized format, if I'm not mistaken. Unfortunately, I can't really help fix that, but I'd recommend first trying to process some other audio files and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I also used the same audio that was given in the original code in the repository. But the problem still persists. @OttoHanski